# How can I display over the entire monitor text?

Tags: c#

My application must collect text from textbox and display that text over entire monitor?

I don't want to see buttons for win form.

Any idea haw to do that? Something like screensaver

Comment: Are you asking how to make a windows form occupy the full screen? If not, what are you asking?

Comment: If you want to draw on *Desktop* directly, look at `GetDesktopWindow`

Comment: Something like screensaver...

Answer (score 0):

Remove buttons by setting ControlBox=false in the Form. Hide everything except your form by setting WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized.

Comment: Also set the Text="" and the MaximizeBox = MinimizeBox = false, maybe the BorderStyle=None, maybe BackColor=TransparenyKey=Colors.Fuchsia..